# Remove selected item in combobox1 from the combobox2. (Comboboxes are bound from database.)

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have 2 comboboxes named `cBTeam1` and `cBTeam2` (winForm & C#) both are bound from same database table.

If a person selects a team from `cBTeam1`, I want this selected team to not be displayed in `cBTeam2`.

```
     private void bindComboBox()
    {
       if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            string queryTeam1 = "SELECT * FROM Teams ORDER BY Team_name";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryTeam1, con);
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(ds, "Teams");

            this.cBoxTeam1.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(this.cBoxTeam1_SelectedIndexChanged);
            cBoxTeam1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Teams"];
            //if(cBoxTeam1.SelectedIndex


            cBoxTeam1.DisplayMember = "Team_name";
            cBoxTeam1.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cBoxTeam1.ValueMember = "team_id";
            this.cBoxTeam1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.cBoxTeam1_SelectedIndexChanged);
   }
```

and here is code for `cBoxTeam2` event handler `cBoxTeam2_SelectedIndexChanged`

```
    private void cBoxTeam2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cBoxTeam1.SelectedIndex == cBoxTeam2.SelectedIndex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You already selected " + cBoxTeam2.Text);
        }


        team2_id = Int32.Parse(cBoxTeam2.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
```

For example `cBoxTeam1` displaye 3 values i.e England, India, Austrailia.
if I Select  India, after selection India shold not be display in the `cBoxTeam2` combobox

Comment: I imagine you already tried to find a solution. What have you done so far?

Comment: @Cedric Bignon,
No bro i havn't find a solution yet. plz help if u can.
and thanks for edition the question.

Comment: I ask you to share what you have done so far because, otherwise your question will be closed. _"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."_

Comment: @CédricBignon, here is my code .... plz check and tell me what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i have made sample for you.Sample have 2 combo box and bind same data source.And when I select `combobox1` firstly check with list if exist bind `combobox 2` except matched item.

```
 protected List<string> lst
    {
        get
        {
            List<string> lst =
                new List<string>();
            lst.Add("1");
            lst.Add("2");
            lst.Add("3");
            return lst;
        }
    }

   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        comboBox1.DataSource = lst;
        comboBox2.DataSource = lst;
    }

   private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lst.Contains(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()))
        {
            comboBox2.DataSource = lst.Select(q => q.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).Where(q => q.ToString() != comboBox1.SelectedItem).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks @neeraj. but i actually want to bind the combobox with database. what should i do in that condition..

Comment: Thats fine! Create property `Dataset` type and bind your combo by dataset like my code.So that you can save your database hit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public void loadcBTeam1()
    {
       ....
       string queryTeam1 = "SELECT Team_name FROM Teams  where Team_name <> '" + yourComboBox2.text + "' ORDER BY Team_name";
     ......
    }
```

and on your ComboBox2 TextChanged

```
   private void comboBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadcBTeam1();
    }
```

Comment: I think that is bad programming practice.For every `selected change` you are hitting database.